# Cumulative Sum Starting at Center of Data Frame - R

Tags: r, dataframe, cumulative-sum

I have this `data.frame` called `dum`

```
   dummy <- data.frame(label = "a", x = c(1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
   dummy1 <- data.frame(label = "b", x = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1))

   dum <- rbind(dummy,dummy1)
```

What I am trying to do is take the cumulative sum starting at 0 in the `x` column of `dum`. The summing would be grouped by the `label` column, which can be implemented in `dplyr` or `plyr`. The part that I am struggling with is how to start the cumulative sum from the 0 position in `x` and go outward.

The resulting `data.frame` should look like this :

```
 >dum
   label x output
1      a 1      4
2      a 1      3
3      a 1      2
4      a 1      1
5      a 0      0
6      a 1      1
7      a 1      2
8      a 1      3
9      a 1      4
10     a 1      5
11     a 1      6
12     a 1      7
13     a 1      8
14     b 1      8
15     b 1      7
16     b 1      6
17     b 1      5
18     b 1      4
19     b 1      3
20     b 1      2
21     b 1      1
22     b 0      0
23     b 1      1
24     b 1      2
25     b 1      3
26     b 1      4
```

This would need to be iterated thousands of times over millions of rows of data.

As usual, thanks for any and all help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems more like you just want to find the distance to a zero, rather than any sort of cumulative sum. If that's the case, then

```
#find zeros for each group
zeros <- tapply(seq.int(nrow(dum)) * as.numeric(dum$x==0), dum$label, max)

#calculate distance from zero for each point
dist <- abs(zeros[dum$label]-seq.int(nrow(dum)))
```

And that gives

```
cbind(dum, dist)

#    label x dist
# 1      a 1    4
# 2      a 1    3
# 3      a 1    2
# 4      a 1    1
# 5      a 0    0
# 6      a 1    1
# 7      a 1    2
# 8      a 1    3
# 9      a 1    4
# 10     a 1    5
# 11     a 1    6
# 12     a 1    7
# 13     a 1    8
# 14     b 1    8
# 15     b 1    7
# 16     b 1    6
# 17     b 1    5
# 18     b 1    4
# 19     b 1    3
# 20     b 1    2
# 21     b 1    1
# 22     b 0    0
# 23     b 1    1
# 24     b 1    2
# 25     b 1    3
# 26     b 1    4
```

Or even `ave` will let you do it in one step

```
dist <- with(dum, ave(x,label,FUN=function(x) abs(seq_along(x)-which.min(x))))
cbind(dum, dist)
```

Comment: works great. took just about 5 minutes on a data frame of 23 million rows in chunks (dum$label in this example) of 14000

Comment: So as to not waste my now deleted answer, a generalisation of this function for multiple 0's in a group would be: `do.call(pmin,lapply(which(dum$x==0), function(n) abs(n-seq_along(dum$x)) ))`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `by` but also with `plyr`, `data.table`, etc. The function that is used on each subset is

```
f <- function(d) {
  x <- d$x
  i <- match(0, x)
  v1 <- rev(cumsum(rev(x[1:i])))
  v2 <- cumsum(x[(i+1):length(x)])
  transform(d, output = c(v1, v2))
}
```

To call it on each subset e.g. with `by`

```
res <- by(dum, list(dum$label), f)
do.call(rbind, res)
```

If you want to use `ddply`

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dum, .(label), f)
```

May be faster with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dumdt <- as.data.table(dum)
setkey(dumdt, label)
dumdt[, f(.SD), by = key(dumdt)]
```

Comment: `dum[,abs(which.min(x) - seq_along(x)),by=label]` would be a simpler `data.table` method.

Comment: Fair enough, @MrFlick 's way is far better anyway if `x` is always either 0 or 1. This wasn't explicitly stated in the OP, so I went for `cumsum`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dum%>% 
group_by(label)%>% 
mutate(dist=abs(row_number()-which.min(x)))
```